# Badge count is cut off on tag pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

For users who have a lot of rep and a lot of badges (like me! but also Sterno), the number of badges is cut off.

Example:
[image]

Screen shot taken from [rogue-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rogue-legacy), [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rogue-legacy).

This is in Chrome 27 in Windows 7.

Comment: No repro in Firefox 22.

Comment: I am able to repro in Firefox 21.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Hm, weird. I confirmed it happening to [both BenBrocka and I](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bKjin.jpg) in Firefox 22 in the [AC:NL tag here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-new-leaf). I'm running Win 7 64-bit.

Comment: I can repro too.  Firefox 22, Win 7.

Comment: I can repro in chrome, however.

Comment: Firefox 24 - repro.

Comment: That said, it's probably a font issue rather than a layout engine issue - the cut off seems to happen from layering and depends on how wide the font is.

Comment: @FEichinger aye: no repro on Chrome 29 on anything but 100% zoom setting.

Comment: Reproduced in Opera 12.16, Opera 15 (Chromium engine), Firefox 22 and Chrome 27.0.1453.94, all on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it on dev, will be on live after our next prod build.